# ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line: Duplicate check constraint name 'CONSTRAINT_1'

Tags: mysql, sql

i have been trying to create a mysql database from an sql file using the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p mydatabse < /home/user/mydata.sql
```

but after a while i get the following error:
ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line: Duplicate check constraint name 'CONSTRAINT_1'.

this is the first time i get this error while creating a database from a dump file.

p.s i have tried other sql file i already used and i didnt have issues, so i suspect the problem is in the sql file im using, but how can i fix this?

Comment: Search for CONSTRAINT_1 and fix..dump files are txt files

Comment: but what is causing this?

Comment: We cannot tell what's wrong in `/home/user/mydata.sql`, it's a local file in your computer's drive we don't have access to. Do you need any clarification on how to follow P.Salmon's advice? That's pretty much all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in your dump file for CONSTRAINT_1 word? I think the word is written twice or more. If so, just rename the duplicate simply changing _1 with _2, _3 and so on.
PS: you can read MySQL dump file with a text file reader.